# how to show metadata associate with a custom document

Tags: metadata, liferay

I would like to view the custom metadata that I associated with the my custom document, that I created with the document library, anyone know how to due with velocity variable?

Thanks in advance
Sabrina
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get some meta-data articles properties with

```
$reserved-article-id.data
$reserved-article-title.data
```

full list you can find [here](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CMS+Template+%28Velocity%29#section-CMS+Template+%28Velocity%29-Getting+data+out+of+different+types+of+fields)

Also you can check this [post](http://java-liferay.blogspot.com/2012/05/get-catgories-at-liferays-cms-template.html), it has example how to get journal's categories at velocity template.

UPD. For getting document metadata you can use smth like this:

```
#set($dlFileUtil =  $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileE‌​ntryLocalService")) 
#set ($groupId = $getterUtil.getLong($groupId)) 
#set($fileEntry = $dlFileEntryUtil.getFileEntryByUuidAndGroupId($uuid,$longGroupId))    
#set($metadataUtil=$serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileE‌​ntryMetadataLocalService"))
```

You can use ***getFileEntryMetadata(ddmStructureId, fileVersionId)*** from ***$metadataUtil***

More detailed code you can check [this](http://liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10805788).

BR,
Paul Butenko

Comment: Hi Paul, what if I want to view the metadata that I setted in document library after create my particular document and then -> metadata set

Comment: You can use smth like this:
#set($dlFileUtil = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalService"))

#set ($groupId = $getterUtil.getLong($groupId))
#set($fileEntry = $dlFileEntryUtil.getFileEntryByUuidAndGroupId($uuid,$longGroupId))
#set($metadataUtil = 
$serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryMetadataLocalService"))
You can use getFileEntryMetadata(ddmStructureId, fileVersionId) from $metadataUtil
More detailed code you can check http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10805788

Comment: This is my output of a file entry created with a custom document with some metadata fields
#set ($fileEntry = $dlService.getFileEntry($gid, $fid, $fileTitle))
$fileEntry -> {uuid=e4e8be71-5fc8-423f-bf82-0d8d08927d50, fileEntryId=12410, groupId=88, companyId=1, userId=2, createDate=.., modifiedDate=.., repositoryId=88, folderId=11563, name=101, extension=png, mimeType=image/png, title=Immagine, description=, extraSettings=, fileEntryTypeId=12408}
From your answer I've noticed that I need a ddmStructureId and a fileVersionId to retrieve the metadata contents. Do you know where I can find its?TNX

Comment: You can check it from this url http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10805788

        DLFileEntry fe;
        if (className.equals(DLFileEntryWorkflowHandler.CLASS_NAME))
            fe = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntry(classPK);

        long fileEntryTypeId = fe.getFileEntryTypeId();
        long versionId = fe.getLatestFileVersion().getFileVersionId();